# React: set width of a div to be the width of an image

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, responsive

I want to make the width of my div be the same width as my image. This includes when you resize the window and the image auto resize. Currently, I tried using useState, but it does not respond when resize.

```
    const basicInfoImage = useRef();
    const basicInfoText = useRef();
    const [basicInfoImageWidth, setBasicInfoImageWidth] = useState();

    useEffect(() => {
        setBasicInfoImageWidth(
            basicInfoImage.current.getBoundingClientRect().width
        );
    });

      <img
        src={profilePic}
        alt="Profile Pic"
        className="About-basic-info-image"
        ref={basicInfoImage}
      />
      <p
        className="About-basic-info-text"
        ref={basicInfoText}
        style={{ width: basicInfoImageWidth }}
      >
        {basicInfoTextContent}
      </p>
```

Comment: Usually, it takes some time for an image to load, and before it has been loaded, the browser won't know its size. If you log `basicInfoImage.current.getBoundingClientRect().width`, do you get a non-zero value? If so, the img tag has an onload event, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39092859/get-dimensions-of-image-with-react

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you're using `useEffect` right now it will only run once when the component mounts. You'll have to add an event listener to the resize event and then call the `setBasicInfoImageWidth`

```
useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener('resize', () => setBasicInfoImageWidth(
        basicInfoImage.current.getBoundingClientRect().width
    ));
});
```

It would probably be simpler to solve this using CSS, although without a working example it would be hard to give you a working snippet. If you add a jsfiddle link I'll be happy to help you out with the CSS

Comment: Yes, I would much prefer to use CSS. My [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hubert322/cx8dzahk/8/)
I specified the width of the div, but I don't want to have to do that, but instead make the div's width to be the width of the image when the image's height is 70%.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow 100%, but try this https://jsfiddle.net/john_flournoy/zq3esmh5/2/

Comment: that was perfect. Could you explain why adding display: inline-block and position: relative in the div and position: absolute in the text could achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with CSS, no need to use react State