# Can anyone explain how to import DriveApp and ImgApp in React, I'm not able to find documentation for this anywhere

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-drive-api

This below code I'm passing inside some function to extract the width and height of the drive image, and I'm passing drive image id to extract the width and height of that. But how to import this DriveApp and ImgApp here.

```
 const blob = DriveApp.getFileById(driveId).getBlob();
 const res = ImgApp.getSize(blob);
 const width = res.width;
 const height = res.height;
```

Comment: First, if your `ImgApp` is https://github.com/tanaikech/ImgApp and if my Google Apps Script library was not useful, I apologize. And, I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your question. Can I ask you about the detail of it?

Comment: Yes @Tanaike, I am working on our company project where there is an option to upload drive image file and for that they are using 'react-google-drive-picker'. but the problem is  I have to run the validation check on all images which were uploaded via Drive, like checking it's width and height. so in order to do that I found the above method, but when I use that I get "DriveApp is not defined". So I wanted to know, where can I get this DriveApp and ImgApp.

Comment: Thank you for replying. First, I have to apologize for my poor skill. My `ImgApp` is for Google Apps Script. And, this library uses the methods for Google Apps Script. By this, unfortunately, this cannot be directly used for React. I think that this is the reason for your issue. If you want to retrieve the size of image data, is this thread useful? https://stackoverflow.com/q/39092859 Or, how about using `ImgApp` after the image data was put to Google Apps Script side?